# Как в Google spreadsheet динамически задать функцию на картинку?

Tags: изображения, google-spreadsheet

Добрый день, у меня 2 вопроса по **Google spreadsheet**:

- как можно динамически через GS вставить картинку стандартной фигуры (квадрат, круг, треугольник и т.д.) в ячейку?
- как динамически через GS назначить вставленной картинке функцию из скрипта?

Ручками через интерфейс делается все просто, а вот как через скрипт это провернуть не в доках не нашел((

Буду благодарен за любые идеи.

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы динамически назначить скрипт, нужно использовать метод `assignScript()`. Например так:

```
var rr = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getImages();
rr[0].assignScript('Ваш скрипт');
```

Сам долго искал ответ на этот вопрос. Потом догадался посмотреть все методы объекта возвращаемого `getImages()`.

Answer (score 0):

По первому вопросу:
1. Создайте в каком-нибудь сайте базу с картинками (можно в том же GoogleSites). При этом кликнув на картинку скопируйте ее веб-адрес.
2. Скопируйте этот адрес в ячейку Google Spreadsheets.
3. В ячейку куда хотите вставлять картинки введите формулу =image("ссылка на ячейку").  "ссылка на ячейку"- к примеру "A1".
4. В скрипте меняйте содержание ячейки указывая различные ссылки на адрес картинке

По второму вопросу:
Кликните на картинку. Справа в ней же вверху появится стрелочка-контекстное меню. Нажмите и выберите в меню "Назначить скрипт"
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, но это все предложенное я сразу нашел.
Однако вопрос не в том как вставить картинку, мне интересно как можно ДИНАМИЧЕСКИ из скрипта создать СТАНДАРТНУЮ фигуру (квадрат, круг, треугольник и т.д.)

А второй вопрос в том, как опять же ДИНАМИЧЕСКИ назначить скрипт, вставленной фигуре.

Но спасибо за ответ, хоть кто-то откликнулся))

Comment: Сожалею, что не смог помочь.. Поискал немного,но не нашел ничего похожего . .Не думаю что с помощью стандартных средств и функций можно это сделать. В принципе в программу можно добавлять html скрипты, а там возможности гораздо шире., но я в этом не еще хуже чем в GoogleScript. Так что удачи вам, а если найдете решение, поделитесь )